# Issues Preserving Format from Word to Excel

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm struggling trying to export a Word table to an Excel sheet, while preserving the number formatting. My code works as shown below, but the part I commented out is how I'm currently trying to do it (and failing). Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
Public Sub CopyTableToExcel()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastColumn As Integer
    Dim tblRange As Word.Range
    Dim excelRange As Excel.Range
    
    Set doc = ThisDocument
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
    Set xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add 'Create new workbook
    
    Set tbl = doc.Tables(2)
    
    With tbl:
    
        lastRow = .Rows.Count
        lastColumn = .Columns.Count
        
        Set tblRange = .Cell(1, 1).Range
        tblRange.End = .Cell(lastRow, lastColumn).Range.End
        tblRange.Copy

        xlwb.Worksheets(1).Paste

        'This part doesn't work, but I'm trying to do something like this:
        'Set excelRange = xlwb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
        'excelRange.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)
       
    End With

    Set xlwb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set tbl = Nothing
    Set doc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "while preserving the number formatting" - what formatting are you referring to? Italic? Bold?

Comment: Sorry, just number formats. For example, copying "0123" results in Excel displaying "0123" vs "123".

Comment: Excel and Word treat numbers differently. Technically Word doesn't contain any numbers, just text (it is after all a *word* processor). In Excel the number format is a property of the cell and determines how the underlying value of the cell is displayed. In your case you probably want the format of cells to be set to Text.     BTW, you can replace all the code for copying the table with `doc.Tables(2).Range.Copy`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: How do I set the properties of the Excel workbook before copying them? I'm trying     `Set excelRange = xlwb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")` then
    `excelRange.NumberFormat = "@" `  but no luck

Comment: Not at a PC right now but I believe you would need to format the entire range you are pasting into, not just one cell.